# Создание объекта класса в цикле

Tags: память, php, объекты

В процессе работы возникла надобность в создании объекта класса в цикле. Цикл может быть размероностью в 1000 и больше итераций. У меня возникают сомнения по поводу использования памяти. Посему вопрос, можно ли так делать?. Готов выслушать все за и против использования данной конструкции.

Пример кода:

```
foreach($entities as $entity) {
    $object = new $class($entity);
    $object->doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете так делать и так делать правильно. Однако, на практике, если в doSomething производятся какие-то полезные действия, то все ссылки на объеты освобождены не будут и потребление памяти скриптом будет расти на каждой итерации. Вы можете произвести замеры через memory_get_usage, чтобы убедиться в этом. Если итераций слишком много, перезапустите скрипт после определенного их количества и продолжайте. Именно такой путь является наиболее примениным на практике.

Answer (score 1):

Данная конструкция не окажет влияния на память. Так как при потере ссылки на объект php удалит его из памяти.

Comment: Спорный вопрос. Утверждение справедливо для простых объектов, ибо мы не знаем наверняка, вдруг там в конструкторе вновь созданный объект засовывается в какую-то коллекцию?